# How to speed up environment loading on network drive?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2

**Background:**

I have about 15 AWS EC2 instances running Windows. They each have local drives and share a single network drive. Each needs to be able to run certain in-development python tools from within a conda environment. These tools cannot currently be compiled into an executable.

My **current solution** is to install a single miniconda environment on the network drive, and host the python tools there as well. This way, whenever a tool or environment needs an update, I update the files on the network drive and all machines now have instant access to the new code.

**Problem:**

The current solution works well, except that it takes about 10 seconds of "startup" time to run these tools. Having all my python code hosted on a network drive means lots of slow reads to load everything into memory.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a better solution to this than hosting the tools and environment on a network drive?
2. How can I speed up the loading time for my tools? Is there a way to cache the conda environment files and/or tools on each machine's local drive, updating when necessary?